# Debugging the logic of a deployed solution on SharePoint 2010 through Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have deployed a solution on a server farm and wish to be able to debug the solution's logic whilst it is running on the server farm, since the problem resides in there, Is there any way or mean by which it is possible to debug a solution (.wsp) which was deployed on a server farm, through the visual studio?

Answer (score 2):

You can either click F5 in Visual Studio and it will deploy the solution and attach a debugger to the appropriate SharePoint process. This can be a little slow but it allows you to debug your code.

You can also manually attach to the SharePoint process from Visual Studio. Go to Debug-->Attach to Process-->Check show processes from all users and sessions-->Select all w3wp.exe processes-->Click attach.

[image]

Comment: once I do that, a break point becomes invalid, is there any particular reason?

Comment: Are you using the F5 or manually attach approach? It can also be a while before all debug symbols are loaded and until then it might say that the breakpoint is invalid. Also just to double check, the solution you deployed is compiled using the Debug configuration?

Comment: does it make sense to have 4 or 2 w3w9.exe processes? also IIS APPPool is not showing in the attach process, even when both tick boxes are ticked. yes it is on debug configuration too

Comment: The App Pools are running in the w3wp.exe processes, so yes, you typically see more then one instance. Are you running Visual Studio in the same server as SharePoint is running?

Comment: no but in the attached image there are 7, so maybe i though there is something missing from my side, yes both are running on the same server.

Comment: What is it that you're deploying? Web Parts, workflows, content types, etc.?

Comment: Is it an application page, with which I have a button which upon click I would like to debug its onclick event handler

Comment: Have you tried browsing to the application page after attaching the debugger? It might be that the debug symbols doesn't get loaded until you browse to the page.